# Magic Square recursion infinte loop java

Tags: java, recursion, magic-square

I'm trying to write a program that can generate all the possible magic squares for a fixed N Dimension. I'm going about it by filling the diagonal cells with values and then filling in the rows with values.

I seem to be stuck in an infinite cycle when fillin in the rows, but can't seem to figure out how or why. I haven't implemented the sum check, to check whether the sum of the rows or columns is correct, but that is irrelevent here.

If anyone can help me out, i'd very greatful.
code bellow

```
public class Magic {

public static final int DIMENSION = 3;
public static final int DIMSQ = DIMENSION * DIMENSION;
public static int[][] array = new int[DIMENSION][DIMENSION];
public static boolean[] boolArray = new boolean[DIMENSION * DIMENSION];
public static final int sum = (DIMENSION * (DIMENSION * DIMENSION + 1)) / 2;

/*
 * Inicializaljuk a matrixunkat, illetve a boolean matrixunkat
 * Initializes the matrix and boolArray with values.
 */
public static void init() {
    for (int e[] : array) {
        for (int e2 : e) {
            e2 = 0;
        }
    }
    for (boolean e : boolArray) {
        e = false;
    }
}

/*
 * Ki irassa a matrix jelenlegi allapotat konzolra
 * Prints the array out to the console.
 */
public static void print() {
    for (int i[] : array) {
        for (int j : i) {
            System.out.print(j + ",");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}

/*
 * feltolti a foatlot adatokkal, majd meghivja a diagonal2-t
 * fills diagonal cells with values
 */
public static void diagonal1(int x) {

    for (int i = 0; i < DIMSQ; i++) {
        if (!boolArray[i]) {
            boolArray[i] = true;
            array[x][x] = i + 1;
            if (x < DIMENSION - 1) {
                diagonal1(x + 1);
            } else
                diagonal2(0);
            boolArray[i] = false;
        }
    }

}

/*
 * feltolti a mellekatlot adatokkal, majd meghivja a row(0,0,0)-t
 * fills diagonal cells with values
 */
public static void diagonal2(int x) {

    for (int i = 0; i < DIMSQ; i++) {
        if (!boolArray[i]) {

            if (array[DIMENSION - 1 - x][x] == 0) {
                boolArray[i] = true;
                array[DIMENSION - 1 - x][x] = i + 1;
            }
            if (x < DIMENSION - 1) {
                diagonal2(x + 1);
            } else
                row(0, 0);
            boolArray[i] = false;
        }
    }
}
/*
 * feltolti a sorokat adatokkal
 * fills rows with values
 */
public static void row(int x, int y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < DIMSQ; i++) {
        if (!boolArray[i]) {

            if (array[x][y] == 0) {
                boolArray[i] = true;
                array[x][y] = i;
            }

            if (x < DIMENSION - 1) {
                row(x + 1, y);
            } else if(y < DIMENSION - 1) { 
                row(0,y+1);
            } else print();

            boolArray[i] = false;

        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    init();
    print();
    diagonal1(0);

}
```

}

Comment: Have you debugged it? In which method does it get stuck?

Comment: it get's stuck while filling out the rows. I know for sure that the diagonal methods  are correct. I've tested them and they worked as imagined. EDIT: to answer, it gets stuck in the row(int x, int y); method.

Comment: Well I'm not sure you're getting off that recursive call `row(x + 1, y);` ever.

Comment: No, i cannot find the specific line.

Comment: could you elaborate? why won't it call that particular method?

Answer (score 0):

My suspect is the `row()` method (see my comments below):

```
public static void row(int x, int y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < DIMSQ; i++) {
        if (!boolArray[i]) {

            if (array[x][y] == 0) {
                boolArray[i] = true; // <-- this one
                array[x][y] = i;
            }

            if (x < DIMENSION - 1) {
                row(x + 1, y);
            } else if(y < DIMENSION - 1) { 
                row(0,y+1);
            } else print();

            boolArray[i] = false; // <-- would be OVERWRITTEN by this one

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a recursive function, so it has to be overwritten whenever it steps back, because it won't use that values, so it has to free it up.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it's infinite, but very long:

9-step loop in `diag1`,
3-deep recrusion to `diag1`,
then 9-step loop in `diag2`
3-deep recursion in `diag2`,
then 9-step loop in `row`
~6-deep recursion in `row`.

Even though not all loops perform complicated operations on each iteration, this can easily add up to hours if you also take into consideration that you print the state of the square at every "resolution" of the square -- printing to console takes time.